# Given $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ and $x\in\mathbb R^n,C\in\mathbb R$ so that $f(x)<C. $ Show there is an $r>0$ so that $f(y)<C$ for all $y\in B_r(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$ is continuous. If there are $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $C\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)<C$, then prove that there is $r>0$ such that for all $y\in B_r(x)$, $f(y)<C$.

---

Maybe one of you could help me with this question I've been stuck on. Not sure how to start or really how to do it at all. This is everything the book gave.

Thanks!

Comment: Whats $B_r(x)$?

Comment: @jnyan most likely the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\epsilon = C-f(x) > 0$. By continuity, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that if $y \in B_{\delta}(x)$, then $f(y) \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$, i.e., $|f(y)-f(x)| < \epsilon = C-f(x)$. This last inequality implies that $f(y) < C$.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof: suppose to the contrary that there is no such $r>0$.

If $n \in \mathbb N$, then there is some $y_n \in B_{1/n}(x)$ such that $f(y_n) \ge C$.

From $||y_n-x|| \le \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ we get: $y_n \to x$

Since $f$  is continuous, we derive $f(x) \ge C$, a contradiction.